# plsql:comparing multiple columns in multiple table with same multiple columns in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables say t1,t2,t3 and each have three different column c1,c2,c3

I have one more table say t4 which has the same three columns as in t1,t2 and t3.(i.e.,c1,c2 and c3 in t4)

How can I compare c1,c2 and c3 with c1 in one stretch?

Is it possible to compare multiple values in one column in one table with multiple values in one column in other table using IN?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "comparing"? Can you show an example of your data and what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

3 tables? 3 columns? Try this.

```
SELECT
    t1.C1
    t1.C2
    t1.C3
    t2.C1
    t2.C2
    t2.C3
    t3.C1
    t3.C2
    t3.C3
FROM  Table1 t1
  INNER JOIN 
      Table2 t2
        ON t1.C1 = t1.C1 AND t2.C1 = t2.C1
           INNER JOIN
              Table3 t3 
                ON t3.C1 = t3.C1
```

Hope Can Help you...

Comment: in where clause i need to compare c1,c2 and c3 in t1,t2 and t3  withsame c1,c2 and c3 in t4

Comment: can you show us your data or explain it more? so that we will know what do you want to achieve.